# IdentityServer 4: have i to encrypt json call to api?

Tags: json, token, identityserver4

i have an identityServer4 with implicit grant and reference token. The client (angular) gets an id token and an access token (reference token). Now i want to do a call to the api with the reference token, so the api can check if the client have access to it. 
At the moment i send a json, with the reference token in it, to the api. That works, but is it secure? can someone else read the communication?

What is the best practice to secure the call from the client to the api and to protect the response from the client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice, and indeed the expectation with all OAuth2 and OIDC calls, is to use SSL. Under the default configuration I believe IS4 will insist you do this anyway, when making any IS-related call.

I should add that there are other flows you can choose instead that avoid the access token being sent to the client, but rather only an authorization code that allows the server to retrieve the real access token using a back-channel to IS. If your UI usage supports this, it will be more secure, as you can avoid exposing the access token to the browser.

See http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html - Authorization Code or Hybrid.

Comment: hm i´m not sure if i understand you correct. I get the access code (i think this is the reference token) from the IS4 to the client and send this code to the API. The Api calls the introspection point from IS4 to check if the access code is correct. the token looks something like this: b6e745573ff6d4365e0c6b72bbc3b14a836f41180f9157d649538a91406e4107. I use a SPA as client so i have to use implicit

Comment: Yes, with Implicit, both tokens are sent to the browser. It's up to you how you protect it after that, and like I say SSL would be the expectation if you're communicating it to anywhere. It's still available in the browser though, so in theory a user could view it there. Using one of the two other flows/grants will result in the access token only being available server-side, which means your initial concern goes away, and you can in theory prevent the browser ever even seeing the access token.

Comment: What you can do with an SPA is use Hybrid, in which case you'll get an Authorization Code in the browser, which is not the Access Token. You then send that to your server, which can use it to retrieve the real Access Token from IS (it needs to supply the Client Secret to do so, hence why it can only feasibly be done server-side, and also why the Authorization Code - if snooped - does not allow a 3rd party to retrieve the real Access Token).